# Set variable inside class

Tags: php, pear

I am using a PEAR S3 Package and I want to set $useSSL = true.
I'm avoiding editing the actual package, thoug I can.

$s3->useSSL->true; pr $s3->useSSL(true); don't work.

S3.php: http://pastebin.com/4sZ19mR4 Line 191

My example code:

```
require_once 'Services/Amazon/S3.php';

$key    = 'xxx';
$secret = 'xxx';
$bucket = 'flyers';

$s3     = Services_Amazon_S3::getAccount($key, $secret);
$s3->useSSL->true;
print $s3->getURL();
$bucket = $s3->getBucket($bucket);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if useSSL is indeed a public property of `$s3`, you could do the following:

```
$s3->useSSL = true;
```

As a side note, you use `$s3->useSSL(true)` only if `useSSL` is defined as a function in the class of `$s3`, whereas `$s3->useSSL->true` means you are trying to access a property named `true` in `useSSL` object in `$s3`, which I'm pretty sure is not what you want.

Comment: @Mike you can thank me by clicking on the `V` sign below the number 1 on the top left of my answer :). No prob in any case, happy to help

Comment: It is indeed a public property: http://pear.php.net/package/Services_Amazon_S3/docs/0.3.5/Services_Amazon_S3/Services_Amazon_S3.html#var$useSSL

Comment: yup/**
     * Whether connections should be made using HTTPS.
     * @var bool
     */
    public $useSSL = false;